# how to sync bunch of photos into firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to do this the efficient way, i have an app that user creates different photos, i want to store all this pics into an storage folder, but i don't want to generate an unique link to each one to have it later, i want to generate like an unique URL for the entire photos folder of the user, there is a way to do this or i need to generate each photo link.

Example

Storage

```
Photos Folder +_
                 All user photos
```

Database

```
URL_FILES :  The entire folder url with all the photos inside
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no such thing as a "folder" object in Cloud Storage.  There are just files with paths that happen to have folder-like structure.

Since there are no folders in Storage, you can't create a link to one.  You'll have to store the individual paths to each of the files if you want to come back to them later.

Comment: there is a way to bulk upload files to the storage ? i mean, making a bundle of photos and then upload all of them at once just generating 1 link for that bundle

Comment: No, you have to upload all the files separately.